# Floating action button background image not fits to the button.and background change on fab click

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

I am duplicating an ios app design to my android app.In ios, it contains a button similar to fab in Android.

**First Issue:**

I tried the fab with four options and it is ok with the options.but the fab background image not fits the fab.

**Android screen :**

[image]

As in the above screen i got all the options but i dont know how to make the background image fit to fab.and some shadows are coming in the fab

**Second Issue**

what i need is once the button clicked four options raises and the background becomes blurry.

**IOS screen before fab click:**

[image]

**IOS screen after fab click**

[image]

***Hope i gave my questions clearly.Thanks in advance.***

Comment: i think it will be easier using a FrameLayout with the Image as an ImageView inside it

Comment: @AjilO. can u please tell me for which issue your answer is?

Comment: it's not an answer. Just a suggestion. That's what I would have done.

Comment: thanks @AjilO. i will try it.

Comment: please show your code